# Debug Jboss 7.x with intellij idea

Tags: jboss, intellij-idea, remote-debugging

I am trying to debug the application on my macbook pro ( os Mountain Lion ). But when I click on debug it is alerting that: `unable to connect localhost 4010`. I set the port to 4010 on jboss. Here is the output while app starting.

```
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 4010
```

On Jidea; settings for debug is "remote server" 
Remote Connection Settings;

```
host : localhost
port : 4010
```

[image: The config ss1]
[image: The config ss2]

Comment: Verify with `lsof -i -P -n | grep 4010` that JVM is listening for debugger connections on this port and check if you connect to this port with `telnet localhost 4010`.

Comment: `java      23750 olgunkaya   11u  IPv4 0x397bad1c774e543d      0t0  TCP *:4010 (LISTEN)`it seems java is listening.

when I started idea and try to debug. then the result is :
 
`java      23750 olgunkaya  392u  IPv4 0x397bad1c6b57775d      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:4010->127.0.0.1:61969 (ESTABLISHED)
idea      23892 olgunkaya  587u  IPv6 0x397bad1c7759dee5      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:61969->127.0.0.1:4010 (ESTABLISHED)`

I am not sure what's going on here.

Comment: Don't you mix up debugger port and HTTP port? **Remote Connection Settings** should specify HTTP port, debugger port is configured in `Startup/Connection`, `Debug`.

Comment: Do you have any updates on this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely you are using debugger port in place for HTTP port:

[image: HTTP port]

[image: Debugger port]

Comment: You are right. I just fixed it. But it is still failing to connect to `localhost 8080` I don't want it to connect remotely. I want it to connect to localhost for debug ( 4010 ). Do I missing something ?

Plus while jboss is starting some parameters passed more than once. I don't think it's an issue but just wanted to clarify and point all : `JAVA_OPTS: -d32 -client -Xms1536m -Xmx1536m -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=4010,suspend=n -Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true....`

Comment: You can use local configuration instead, IDEA will start JBoss with the correct options automatically.

Comment: well, I don't want Idea to start jboss but it seems it will push me to there. I'll look for another options. But this is really a bad one!

Comment: As for the 8080 connection problem, can you open this page in a browser? What URL would you use? Duplicate parameters can be passed because you've modified environment or startup script incorrectly.

Comment: well locahost:8080 is the "Wellcome to AS 7" page.

Comment: Please update your question with the problem details. Attach a screenshot with the error. It's not clear what exactly doesn't connect.

Answer (score 3):

In case if you just want to connect to your local application server:

1. Open "Run/Debug configurations" window.
2. Add new configuration - **Remote**
3. Set up Port to your Jboss socket port